# Como eliminar el método de pago por defecto de Stripe checkout

Tags: javascript, stripe

Actualmente estoy construyendo una tienda de comercio electrónico como proyecto personal y quiero usar Stripe Checkout para poder realizar cobros.

Siguiendo la documentación he logrado hacer una implementación de Stripe Checkout funcional pero tengo la siguiente duda.

Cuando un usuario le permite a stripe guardar los datos de su método de pago (al hacer click en la casilla de la siguiente imagen),

[image: Formulario de stripe checkout con casilla para recordar datos de método de pago]

la próxima vez que visite el checkout encontrará el formulario lleno con los datos que suministró anteriormente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero saber es si es posible eliminar esta tarjeta en caso de que el cliente ya no quiera que Stripe recuerde sus datos de pago.

Creo que podría lograrlo con ayuda del método [stripe.customers.deleteSource](https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/delete?lang=node) pero para poder usarlo necesito el id de la tarjeta que quiero borrar y el problema es que cuando intento obtener las tarjetas de algún customer con [stripe.customers.listSources](https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/list?lang=node) obtengo una lista vacía.

### Actualización 1

Logré obtener los métodos de pago de un usuario usando [stripe.customers.listPaymentMethods](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/customer_list) después de añadir el par clave valor payment_intent_data.setup_future_usage: "on_session" al momento de crear una session de checkout.

Usé el método [stripe.paymentMethods.detach](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/detach) pasando como parámetro el id del payment_method que obtuve pero aun así stripe sigue recordando los datos de la ultima tarjeta de crédito que use.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar la API para listar los metodos de pago de un Customer: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/customer_list

Y luego utilizar la API de detach: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/detach

De todas formas el cliente puede administrar sus metodos de pago asociados en app.link.co:

[image: el cliente puede administrar sus metodos de pago asociados en app.link.co]

Comment: Cuando ejecuto el detach stripe solo elimina el vinculo entre los objetos customer y payment_method pero continua recordando los datos de la tarjeta de forma que cuando completo un proximo pago se crea un nuevo payment_method con todos los datos de la tarjeta anterior

Comment: no comprendo como acceder a  app.link.co